# Redemption with O365 and Creating New Profiles

Tags: outlook, office365, profile, mapi, outlook-redemption

I'm so glad to see Redemption has survived into the 2020s! I used to use redemption many many years ago & LOVED it. I'm curious, how does it go with profile creation on Win11 / Outlook 365?

I need to push new profiles to a bunch of machines (multiple profiles per machine). Would Redemption be able to do this?

Thanks for the good code!
Tony.

Comment: Of course. Please see https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#ROH_Profile_Outlook2016

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I think it should be posted as an answer with a source code sample.